# Copying columns with a specific value from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am using Google Docs Sheet for editing

[image]

I want to find out a way to copy the "Name" and "Variety" columns into another sheet where the "Germination %" column is 0.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

An apps script solution, using the [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) trigger or a [time-based](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) one. Depending on the size of the Sheet I'd recommend using the time based one.

Eg.

```
function onEdit( e ){
  rang = e.range.getRange();
  if( rang.getColumn() == 9 && rang.value() == "0" )
    SpreadshettApp.openById(newId).appendRow( e.source.getRange(rang.getRow(), 1, 1, -1).getValues() );
}
```

Or you could display the results using the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function.